# New to ActiveRecord. Is SQL knowledge important?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have no experience in SQl databases. I just started using ActiveRecord and I find myself compy pasting the ActiveRecord query statements beucase I don't know difference between when to use .find() .where(), joins etc. There's so many ways to do one query and I am ovewhemled. I am just wondering if it's a good idea to take a step back and learn SQL first or jus try to follow along? Also if what's the best way to learn SQL?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes! You should definitely know SQL to use ActiveRecord effectively.

AR improves productivity by abstracting you away from the tedium of writing raw SQL, but an understanding of what it's doing will improve your usage of it, as well as your ability to write effective code.

You could start by watching your logs with `tail -f log/development.log` while you work, which will show you the statements generated by AR. This will help you gain a frame of reference to help you see what AR is doing for a given call.

AR doesn't replace SQL - it augments it by letting you use it at a higher level. Understanding what's going on under the hood will only help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you know SQL basics then it's easy to use ActiveRecord.

- To learn SQL basics you can use [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp).
- To learn ActiveRecord use [this link](http://marklunds.com/s5/rails101/html/active_record_basics.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend learning SQL first, it will help you out ALOT in the long run. Active Record really is just an [Object-Relational Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) of the database that helps to make writing the SQL cleaner, clearer, and easier. That being said I do not think it is a replacement to know SQL, not to mention it is pretty easy to learn the basics. I would suggest looking at both documentation on SQL as well as active record.

SQL: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Active Record: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html And http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html